# Prefix column index to column names in list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, list, lapply

I'd like to prefix column numbers to column names in a data frame.  What's the best way of doing this?

For example, I'd like something like "1_mpg", "2_cyl" in the following table:

```
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6)), .Names = c("mpg", 
"cyl"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"), class = "data.frame")
```

And then how about extending that to a list of data frames?

```
list(structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6)), .Names = c("mpg", 
"cyl"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"), class = "data.frame"), 
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6)), .Names = c("mpg", 
"cyl"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"), class = "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using (though I'm guessing there's something more elegant):

```
# sample list of 2 data frames
x =
  list(structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6)), .Names = c("mpg", 
  "cyl"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"), class = "data.frame"), 
  structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6)), .Names = c("mpg", 
  "cyl"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"), class = "data.frame"))

# create function to append an index to column names
newColNames = function(a) {
          b=lapply(seq_along(colnames(a)), 
          function(i) paste(i,"_",colnames(a)[i],sep=""))
          colnames(a)=b
          return(a)
          }

# apply function
new_list = lapply(x, function(y) newColNames(y))
```